# Tensorflow 2 multiple models on same GPU speed improvement

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to do hyperparameter search for a LSTM using a small-ish data set. I've saved the code I'm using for hyperparameter search in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenwong/60b47836a45d62fe93dff04d99f70aac). As you can see, the code is fairly vanilla. I've already set memory growth to `True` as per documentation like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
except:
    print('Could not set GPU memory growth')
    pass
```

The LSTM itself is very vanilla.

```
nn = input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(200,2))

for l in layers:
    # layers is [{'units' : 16}]
    nn = keras.layers.LSTM(**l)(nn)

output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(output_dim, activation=output_activation)(nn)

model = keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt)
```

If I run this code using a single process, I get ~300us/sample. If I run this with 10 processes, I get 2ms/sample, which means I'm hardly getting any benefits from running things in parallel. I'm just wondering what performance benefits others are seeing?

My spec: Ryzen 3700X, 64gb RAM, RTX 2060 6gb, Windows 10, Python 3.7, Tensorflow 2.2. From Task Manager, CPU/memory usage is ~50%, GPU usage is apparently only ~6-8%

[Edit] I forgot to mention that input is already preprocessed. So each process is literally just creating the model then feeding data into the GPU